# Parse a dragged path from a remote machine

Tags: filenames, nautilus, gvfs, drag-and-drop

I am writing an application that needs to be able to parse a path that is dragged from a remote server onto the command line. However, when I drag a path from a remote machine to the terminal I get something that looks like the following:

`/home/user/.gvfs/sftp for Name on server-alias/the/full/path/is/here.file`.

I would like just

`/the/full/path/is/here.file`

to be parsed. I was wondering if there's a setting I can tweak to prevent this extra path prefix (preferable) or if there's some built in functionality somewhere in linux to do this. I can of course use regexs to parse this, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

I'm on ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this tutorial titled: [Scripting the Linux desktop, Part 2: Scripting Nautilus](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-script-linux-desktop-2/), which discusses how to add your own items to Nautilus' right click context menu as well as which variables Nautilus provides you when manipulating/dragging objects around inside of it.

#### example

Variables presented in Nautilus.

```
Environment variable                  Description
--------------------                  -----------
NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS   Newline-delimited paths for selected files (only if local)
NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_URIS         Newline-delimited URIs for selected files
NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI           The current location
NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_WINDOW_GEOMETRY       The position and size of the current window
```

In Python, you obtain the value of these variables with a single call to the `os.environ.get` function as follows:

```
selected = os.environ.get('NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS,'')
```